# Video error in iOS SDK 3.2.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, playback

I get a strange error since upgrading to 3.2.5:

> Undefined symbols:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-MPMoviePlayerViewController in SecondView.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here's the code that always worked before.

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"m4v"];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
          initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding it?

Comment: yes, I've rebuilt several times. What's strange is my earlier builds with this video code don't throw the error, just the new builds.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your xcode.
project menu -> edit active target -> in that select plus symbol in the bottom left corner. Now select mediaframework and build the code. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it with this code: NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"xing test" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];